# Windows does not boot - black screen with blinking cursor

Tags: linux, windows-xp, boot, grub2, lubuntu

In /dev/sda1 I restored Windows image with clonezilla (previously working with this hardware). From this time, I can not boot to Windows, black screen with blinking cursor is appeared.

Then I installed Lubuntu to another partitions and dual boot is managed by GRUB. The problem with Windows booting remains.

Here is code from GRUB:

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1     --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  02F00451F0044CFB
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 02F00451F0044CFB
fi
parttool ${root} hidden-
drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
chainloader +1
```

(If it helps, here are [my windows boot files from /dev/sda1](http://snk.to/f-cdc34is9).)

Comment: Did you try booting off a Windows XP install/rescue DVD?

Answer (score 0):

Current setting expect Windows XP to be on partition 1 with ID 02F00451F0044CFB.

First of all Windows XP boot files must be on active partition.

Then if Windows XP was restored to a partition different than par1 and the partition ID is different change accordingly grub.conf and "boot.ini".

You could fix only boot.ini (if necessary) manually and rerun grub install in Lubuntu - this will find Windows XP and change grub.conf accordingly.